# How to add Windows Mobile 6.1 image to VS 2008 Device Emulator Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile

I have VS 2008 SP1 on my pc, also Virtual PC and ActiveSync 4.5 is installed
I just download and install "Windows Mobile 6.1 Emulator Images" msi from microsoft

but after install, Mobile images not add to Device Emulator Manager (Under DataStore)

What's problem and how to solve it ?

Thanks
Hamid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3D6F581E-C093-4B15-AB0C-A2CE5BFFDB47&displaylang=en) page carefully it requires the [Windows Mobile 6 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&displaylang=en) to be installed first.

They work for me and I have the WM6 SDK installed.  The WM6.1 emulator images are listed along side the WM6 images.